# Specifying hexadecimal colour in RMarkdown YAML header

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I have the following RMarkdown file:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Mr. Test"
date: "September 5, 2018"
output: pdf_document
urlcolor: red
---

[URL](www.google.com)
```

This produces the following:

[image]

The red link leads to www.google.com, as expected. Awesome. Now, say I wanted my URLs to be a nameless hexadecimal colour, say, `#FF3300`. I have tried various approaches to providing this colour without success. For example, `#FF3300` is ignored as it is interpreted as a comment; `"#FF3300"` throws an error, as does `"0xFF3300"` and `0xFF3300`. So, my question: what is the correct syntax when specifying hexadecimal colours in a YAML header?

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe: that refers to markdown not YAML. That answer doesn't answer this question.

Comment: [The 68 standard colors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips) work by name. Haven't had success defining colors in the preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't seem to figure out how to properly escape the YAML header with `urlcolor:`, but you can explicitly include a header. You just need to encode the color value as three numbers 0-1 indicating the intensity of red, green, blue

```
title: "Test"
author: "Mr. Test"
date: "September 5, 2018"
output: "pdf_document"
header-includes:
    - \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor = [rgb]{1,.2,0}}
```

Though #FF3300 is pretty close to red so it doesn't look much different in the output.

I don't think the problem is with YAML at all. The problem is that the color is done by `hyperref` and that'a LaTeX packaage that understands LaTeX colors rather than R color values. And the second problem is that rmakrdown or kniter or some combination is trying to escape the brackets and braces in those values such that it messed up the values when creating the LaTeX code via the `urlcolor` parameter.